# Is there a way to export data from Android Profiler?

Tags: android, profiler, android-profiler

I would like to export data from Android Profiler, I would like to create a comparison graph between two applications. Problem is that I would like to get a percentage of say RAM-usage over a timespan. I know I could do it manually by hovering over the timeline. Problem is this would take an extremely long time doing it for both of the applications, covering both CPU and RAM.

Yes, I've done it manually just for one of the application, but the values aren't correct.

How would I go to tackle this problem. Anyone here that had experience working with Android Profiler and collecting data to later make a graph of some sort out of it?

Would appreciate the help or a beneficial way to do it.

Comment: What data exactly are you looking for? CPU/RAM usage over a period of time? If the tool could export the data in a spreadsheet (e.g. CSV format), would that be helpful to you? Feel free to open a feature request at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192708&template=840533 and the team can look into it. Thanks!

Comment: @YiYang , that would be more than helpful, I am doing report that has the deadline in the beginning of June, doing a feature request now will not help so much though....

Comment: In that case, if your app is targeting Android Q and above, you can look into the command line tool Perfetto (https://perfetto.dev/), which offers a SQL-like interface for querying data in a trace.